# JTabbedPane trigger event

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtabbedpane, changelistener

I want to trigger an event whenever the "+" tab is clicked (and no other tabs present).  Basically, I want the "+" tab to act like a button. I'm not quite sure which type of listener to use.  How can I do this?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class JTPTest extends JTabbedPane {



    public JTPTest() {

        this.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
                System.out.println(changeEvent);
            }

        });

        JPanel blankJPanel = new JPanel();
        this.addTab("+", blankJPanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new JTPTest());

                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> JPanel blankJPanel1 = new JPanel();
> this.addTab("+", blankJPanel1);
> ```

```
setModel(new DefaultSingleSelectionModel() {

    @Override
    public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
        System.out.println("woah!");
    }
});
```

**Update**

Just an alternative version, without the need of modifying the model behavior.

> ```
> JPanel blankJPanel = new JPanel();
> this.addTab("dummy text", blankJPanel);
> ```

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("x");
label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("woah!!");
    }
});


setTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(blankJPanel), label);
```

**Update 2**
Seems I end up doing something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24024174/3697851), please refer to it as the "best" solution to this problem.

Comment: So, yes that works when you have multiple tabs... but I want the + to invoke a listener (acting like a button) when there is only 1 tab.  I updated the question to make that more clear.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited the question. I believe you cannot establish a listener on the tabs, since no new selection is made. Instead, you can override the behavior on the selection model.

Comment: Thanks... This is very close to what I'm looking for.  The only issue is that the event only happens the first time the tab is clicked.  Any thoughts on how to make it repeatable?

Comment: Edited again. By removing the default behavior "super.setSelectedIndex(index);" the selection keeps repeating on multiple clicks.

Comment: Adding a ChangeListener to the tabbed pane would achieve the same  thing without the need to replace the SelectionModel, which potentially cause issues if the you need to replace the SelectionModel for other reasons...

Comment: Agreed with MadProgrammer, is not flexible. (It also causes issues when having multiple tabs, since the index selection is not persisted on the model).

Comment: `Just an alternative version, without the need of modifying the model behavior.` - as has already been suggested.

Comment: Oh boy, I think you are right, I ended up in the same place. While I did not use your answer (I was looking at the sources and found out about the Page tabComponent reference), I believe it's a similar procedure. I apologize for the imprudence, you can take the credit for this.

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

One of the examples shows how to add a "Close" button to a tab. You should be able to easily modify the code to add a "+" button.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking..   I want to trigger an event when the +  tab is clicked and it is the only tab.

Comment: @dubdubdubdot, `but I want the + to invoke a listener (acting like a button) when there is only 1 tab.`  Your current code doesn't work because you don't get a ChangeEvent generated when you only have a single tab. Clicking on the "+" button will invoke the ActionListener of the "+" button no matter how many tabs you have in the tabbed pane.

Comment: I see your point, but I want the tab itself to act like a button, not have a button on the tab.

Comment: @dubdubdubdot, you don't have to add a button. You can add any component. Or you can add a button without a Border, so that is looks like a normal label with text.